# datepicker work once in partialview mvc5

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm having this annoying problemwith datepicker.
I'm working with MVC5, Bootstrap 3.2, jquery 1.10.2 and jquery-ui-1.11.1. 
I have 2 datepickers in a partial view that is call it from a bs modal, and when I show the modal a second time, the datepicker stop working, and I've tried almost everything, take a look:

**JS Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        $("#EDate").datepicker();
        $("#RDate").datepicker({ minDate: "-1d" });

        $("#divm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
            $(".datepicker").removeClass("hasDatepicker").removeAttr('id');
        })
    })();
</script>
```

**Razor Code**

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EntryDateOperation, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "EDate", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EntryDateOperation, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "RDate", @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
```

**The bootstrap modal**

```
<div id="divm" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Embarcaciones" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="text-align:right">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <div style="text-align:left">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="mTitulo">Nueva Embarcaci&oacute;n</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mEdit" class="modal-body" style="width:100%; text-align:center">
                @{Html.RenderPartial("_myclass", Model.Myclass);}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**and I added z-index on jquery ui css**

```
.ui-datepicker {
    width: 17em;
    padding: .2em .2em 0;
    display: none;
    z-index: 9999999 !important;
}
```

As you can see I have tried almost everything, but I don't know what else can I  do, Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: You destroy all date pickers when the modal hides, but only create them once at startup. Of course it will not work again. Reattach the datepickers when needed.

Comment: I've tried this and nothing:

Comment: $("#divm").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
            $("#EDate").datepicker();
            $("#RDate").datepicker({ minDate: "-1d" });
        });

Comment: Can you save the HTML output of the actual page from a browser, so we can mock-up a JSFiddle? The server-side Razor code is not necessary to solve this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/lebarros/uhpxcm4j/

Comment: That helps. Here is an update with jQuery + jQuery UI + style added: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/uhpxcm4j/2/ but it still needs the rest of the page HTML & code to actually run the modal. Not just those snippets. Thanks.

Comment: I have added the call but is not working, http://jsfiddle.net/lebarros/uhpxcm4j/9/

Comment: Don't make changes to your original JSFiddle. Change mine (it has jQuery etc added) :) I will fix

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uhpxcm4j/12/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62768/discussion-between-trueblueaussie-and-user3384846).

Comment: Please stop using "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap", because it means something else

Answer (score 0):

You were removing the id attribute from the elements, so you could not find them again to reconnect the datepicker. Get id of `removeAttr('id')`:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/uhpxcm4j/15/

```
 $(function () {
     $("#divm").on("show.bs.modal", function () {
         console.log("show.bs.modal");
         $("#EDate").datepicker();
         $("#RDate").datepicker({
             minDate: "-1d"
         });
     });

     $("#divm").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
         console.log("hidden.bs.modal");
         $("#EDate,#RDate").datepicker("destroy").removeClass('datepicker').removeClass("hasDatepicker");
     });

     $("#nuevo").click(function(){
         $("#divm").modal("show").show();
     });

 });
```

Note I made other changes, just to get it working in that fiddle.

Comment: Nop, still got nothing :(

Comment: Its just the initial modal showing that is fooling you. 1) click nuevo. Select field. Date picker comes up. 2) close modal 3) click nuevo and select field again. Date picker comes up again. It's all because we do not have all of Bootstrap in the JSFiddle.

Comment: I'm uploading a video so you can see my problem, because I follow by the letter all your instructions and I get nothing :( I really apreciate your help

Comment: I am using Chrome if that helps you test the JSFiddle.

Comment: I'm using Chrome too, take a look that's my error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3hXVJxHzGI

Comment: Aha.. That is in your final project.. Did the JSFiddle work for you? I am just waiting for your new points to kick in so we can chat.

Comment: I tried your JSFiddle and didn't work :( The video it's with the jsfiddle code